# liquibase does not run with java -jar SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I am trying to integrate liquibase with an existing project. When testing liquibase locally I have been using IntelliJ which I think is equivalent to `mvn spring-boot:run` in this case when the app starts liquibase runs the update and checks that all the changelogs have been completed.

When I compile into a jar (`mvn clean install`) and run `java -jar app.jar` liquibase simply prints out:

```
 15:17:08.769 [main] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully acquired change log lock
 15:17:09.013 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Creating database history table with name: "app".databasechangelog
 15:17:09.028 [main] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from "app".databasechangelog
 15:17:09.078 [main] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully released change log lock
```

and does not apply any of the changesets so obviously it immediately crashes because none of the tables have been set up (if I'm running it on a new database). My understanding is that in a spring boot app with default configuration liquibase should run on start up. I thought that this could be a dependency issue but then why would liquibase be running at all?

Can anyone give some pointers on what I can check to support this? Does liquibase just not run on startup unless it's a specific "spring boot run"?

Thanks

Changelogs added by request:

**db.changelog-root.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd"
                   logicalFilePath="root"
>
    <!-- NOTE: path is relative from src/main/resources -->
    <includeAll path="./db/changelog"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**changelog-2.5.0.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog logicalFilePath="2.5.0" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">
    <preConditions onFail="WARN" onFailMessage="Non postgres databases are not supported for SI, good luck!">
        <dbms type="postgresql"/>
    </preConditions>
    <changeSet author="kidd (manual)" id="tag-version-2.1.0">
        <tagDatabase tag="2.5.0"/>
    </changeSet>

    <!-- mobile_uid_seq -->
    <changeSet author="kidd (modified)" id="1635825727316-1">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <sequenceExists sequenceName="mobile_uid_seq"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <createSequence cacheSize="1" cycle="false" dataType="bigint" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="-1" sequenceName="mobile_uid_seq" startValue="-1"/>
    </changeSet>

<!-- ... a lot more changesets --> 
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Show your databasechangelog file

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I have added the changelogs, though as I stated the changelogs are working perfectly when running in IntelliJ or using `mvn:spring-boot run` so I don't think the issue is the changelogs themselves.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan actually I take that back! As a sanity check I added a changelog to the root and it was successfully applied. So I think the issue that the relative path in the <includeAll> statement is not working on the compiled jar but does work when running with spring boot... still unsure what the issue is there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing

`<includeAll path="./db/changelog"/>` to `<includeAll path="/db/changelog"/>`. Though if anyone could explain why this would be different between running the compiled jar (`java -jar app.jar`) and `mvn:spring-boot run` that would be interesting to me. I understand that the filepaths change when compiled however, even looking in the `target` folder it should still be the same relevant path right (in this case `db` is the root folder following the normal liquibase layout). So still slightly confused as to why `./` should not work in this case.

Regardless, if anyone faces this problem again do not use relative paths even when within the resources folder!